Relaying Ctrl-C on to remote machine through reverse ssh tunneling
I set up a reverse-ssh tunneling connection from my local machine to a remote server using the following ssh config setup
Host remote
  RemoteForward 2222 localhost:22
  Hostname 192.168.1.111
  User user
  ForwardAgent yes
  ForwardX11 yes
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
  XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth

I then ssh into the remote machine via ssh remote. From the remote machine I'm trying to run a command on my local machine by, say:
ssh -n localhost -p 2222 "while true ; do sleep 1 ; date ; done"

When I press Ctrl-C, the ssh connection is lost. However, the process for while true ; do sleep 1 ; date ; done keeps running on the local machine. How is it possible to relay the Ctrl-C (SIGINT) to the local machine?

I realize my question is similar to such as:
Ctrl-C handling in SSH session
How is Ctrl+c or Ctrl+z sent over SSH?
However, I can't use -t to prevent ssh from catching the Ctrl-C. If I type:
ssh -t -n localhost -p 2222 "while true ; do sleep 1 ; date ; done"

I get:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.


"because stdin is not a terminal" – Because you used -n…

See also How to prevent CTRL+C from breaking ssh connection?

And How to terminate remotely called "tail -f" when connection is closed?

Thanks @KamilMaciorowski! That was the reason it didn't work. Now it works when I removed -n.

Beware of the side effects of using -t (as mentioned at the link I gave above).

@muru, that's not related.
